# how to find datalist control in sub control in .aspx.cs page

Tags: asp.net

this is my  designe code

My Profile
            
            
                
                    
                    **First Name:**
                    '>

```
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtfname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fname") %>' Visible="true"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <b>Last Name:</b>
                <asp:Label ID="lname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lname") %>'></asp:Label>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtlname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lname") %>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <b>Gender:</b>
                <asp:Label ID="gen" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("gender") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="gender" runat="server" Visible="false">
                 <asp:ListItem>.....Select Color....</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>

                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
                <b>Mobile:</b>
                <asp:Label ID="mo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("mo") %>'></asp:Label>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtmo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("mo") %>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <b>E-Mail:</b>
                <asp:Label ID="email" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("email") %>'></asp:Label>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtemail" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("email") %>' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                 <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="edite_click"/>
            </div>
            <div>

                <div class="Details" style="margin-left: 135px">


                    <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="linkedite" runat="server" OnClick="edite_click" >Edite<span></span></asp:LinkButton>--%>
                    <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="linkdelete" runat="server" OnClick="update_click" >Update<span></span></asp:LinkButton>--%>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>


    </asp:DataList>
```

i want text box propety visible true when i  will click link button.
when user click on link butto then fire onclick event and all text box must be shown means visibel true

Comment: It looks like you already roughly know what to do. What do you need help for ? It's not very clear what you want.

Comment: Provide formatted code for understanding.

Comment: when user click link button  then all text box visible property must be true